PhpSpreadsheetで改行された文字列を取得するには
お世話になります。
PhpSpreadsheet で、エクセルを読み込み、
取得したデータをDBから検索し、一致するデータを取得する処理を行っています。
DBに一致するデータがある前提で、
Excelから取得したセルの値が改行されている場合、その値をDBで検索した結果ヒットしません。
改行がないセルは検索できるので、改行が関係しているかと思うのですが、解決方法を見つけられずにおります。
もし分かる方がいらっしゃいましたら、
教えていただけますと幸いです。
